# Is it possible to use OpenCL on a minimal OS without X?

Tags: linux, x11, gpu

I'm looking to use OpenCL for Bitcoin mining. Obviously it is technologically possible to use a GPU and OpenCL without X; Windows machines do it all the time. I'm wondering if there is a way to use OpenCL on a graphics card on Linux or similar without installing/running X. About a year ago I read that this was not possible, but I figure that what I read may be incorrect and/or things may have changed in the last year.

Is it possible now? How can it be done? Would it provide any performance improvement (theoretical or actual) when mining Bitcoins?

Comment: Have you tried any OpenCL sdk yet, ATI's or Nvidia's

Comment: I, unfortunately, have not had a chance to try this on an actual computer yet. I was hoping to know more before then, but I may try soon.

Comment: If I rememmber correctly, AMD is working on opencl without X dependency, but at the moment, wokring Xorg session is needed for opencl calculations on graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **xvfb**. I used it to run a download client based on mono and some graphical stuff on a machine without graphics card and monitor.

Comment: I think you're answering the opposite question to the one being asked; he wants to access the graphics card without running X, while you are talking about running X without a graphics card.

Comment: Ok, in that case some links: CUDA(Nvidia) on [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cuda) and on [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda). A link for [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/pages/DriverCompatibility.aspx) and [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk). Hope it helps...